# Question: Are you all reading about Donald Knuth, "The Yoda of Silicon Valley" in the New York Times today?

Tags: discussion, fun

Don't miss the article. No MWE for this one.

Comment: I believe the chat is a better place to share such information with the community, and, in fact. it [has been shared there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=48104026#48104026).

Comment: Indeed. I rarely chat.

Comment: @marmot but in chat it soon disappers from view. I think here is better for historical reason, even if it is off-topic.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Originally it was on the main site. On this site it makes more sense, I agree.

Comment: @marmot Yay, great article!

Comment: @marmot It might make more sense on the main site. The question is related to tex and not to the software that powers tex.se (which is the topic of tex.meta)

Comment: @samcarter My thinking is that this is not a question that can be answered (in the usual sense), and on meta it is possible to have a discussion.

Comment: @marmot Discussion can happen on meta, but the discussion should be about "the workings and policies of TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange rather than discussing TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems itself." (https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) Maybe the question just does not fit in the stackexchange framework (It would be well suited for one of the tex mailing list, or http://texblog.net/)

Comment: @samcarter Yes, that's why I suggested the chat.

Comment: @marmot Ah yes, that is a good advice :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this article, which I will read religiously, hoping (but not believing) that he will have been asked what his purpose was when he allowed the tokens to be modified :-)

Comment: Once upon a time we had a blog...

Comment: “It started out that computer scientists were worried nobody was listening to us. Now I’m worried that too many people are listening.” — That closing statement is pretty spot on, and shows infinitely more self-consciousness than most tech gurus.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, we are all reading

[image]